# cat gives different error when opening non-existing file

Tags: command-line, io-redirection, cat

Both of the following commands try to open a non-existing file `foo`, but the error messages are a little different. What could be the reason?

```
$ cat foo
cat: cannot open foo
$ cat < foo
-bash: foo: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Guys, please do not downvote posts only based on formatting, especially for posts coming from newcomers. Here, it's a very valid question.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel: Hey!  [Be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)!

Comment: Loosely related: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216)

Comment: Only the first error comes from `cat`. Now, I wonder where the second message comes from, considering that it starts with `bash:`...

Comment: However for some reason, when I run two commands, I get the same output(the 2nd output which is more common). I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 30):

```
cat foo
```

This runs the `cat` command with argument `foo`. The error printed onscreen depends entirely on what was decided by the programmer of the command `cat`.

```
cat < foo
```

This feeds the contents of the file `foo` to the `cat` command by using the [Bash stdin redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). If the file doesn't exist, it is Bash that complains about it, not `cat`.

Answer (score 20):

In `$ cat foo` the shell (here bash) executes the `cat` command and passes the parameter `foo`. The cat program chooses to interpret that parameter as a file name - and tries to open the file.
The error you see is from the cat program which (naturally) cannot open the file.

The version `$ cat < foo` is a redirection which is handled by the shell. `<` is a shell operator which instructs the shell to open a file and redirect it to stdin. The file does not exist so you get a "No such file" and `cat` is not even run. This time the error comes from the shell (bash) and looks a little different.

This is why you see 2 different errors. The cause is the same - but it is from 2 different programs (cat and bash).

Comment: No. in `cat < foo`, `cat` is not invoked if the redirection fails. That (and having consistent error message) is one reason why it's often better to use redirection where possible. Also consider the `cat < in > out` vs `cat in > out` where the former prevents `out` to be overridden if `in` doesn't exist (the shell cancels the command right after the failing `< in` redirection and doesn't do the next `> out` redirection, let alone invoke `cat`).

Comment: Cool! Pure logic. I'll edit my nonsense.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Hello, why is it better to use the redirection operator wherever possible?

Comment: @FuRinKaZan_001, it is not necessarily always better, but there are several advantages in most cases where it's possible. See for instance [When should I use input redirection?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/70759)