# How is this command legal? "> file1 < file2 cat"

Tags: shell, io-redirection

Assuming `file2` already exists, the command

```
> file1 < file2 cat
```

appears to be copying the content of `file2` to `file1`.

But I cannot understand this structure.

I understand that "Nothing" is being directed to `file1` (creating or erasing its content).
Then the content of `file2` is being directed to `file1`.

Why is `cat` after `file2`? How does it know to `cat file2` if the operands are not in the correct order?

Comment: What "correct order"? Can you provide a link to some resource / learning material where a "correct order" is described?

Comment: When asking questions like this, you should specify the shell; different ones have different edge cases, especially around redirection.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Before the shell executes the `cat` command on the command line, it handles any redirections.  Redirections include redirecting input or output using `<` (stdin, read-only), `<>` (stdin, read+write), `>` (stdout, write-only) and `>>` (stdout, write-only, appending output), but also `<<word` (here-documents) and `<<<'...'` (in some shells, "here-strings").  These redirection operators should occur unquoted to have the effect of redirecting input or output, and you can prepend a number to specify which file descriptor to redirect instead of the default (stdin (0) or stdout (1) depending on the operator).

There are two redirections in the command that you show:

1. `>file1`  This will make the command's standard output go to `file1`.
2. `<file2`  This will make the command's standard input come from `file2`.

The fact that these redirections are placed in a wonky location on the command line doesn't matter.

```
$ cat <file2 >file1
```

is the same as

```
$ <file2 cat >file1
```

which is the same as

```
$ <file2 >file1 cat
```

etc.¹

Note that the `cat` utility in all of these instances is executed *without any command line arguments*.  The redirections are not operands to the `cat` command, they are instructions to the shell to set up redirections into and out of the command (connecting its standard input and output to files). The shell sets up the redirections *before* invoking the command.

The difference between `cat file` and `cat <file` (or, if you will, `<file cat`) is that in the first case, the `cat` utility itself is opening the file, which is given as an operand on the command line, for reading, while in the second case, the *shell* will open the file and connect `cat`'s input stream to it². In the second case, `cat` will notice it wasn't given a file operand and will automatically switch to reading from its standard input. This is a feature of `cat`, and of some other utilities, not something that all utilities do.

`cat` will also read from its standard input if it's given the operand `-`.  Again, this is special only to `cat` and to some other utilities (i.e. nothing that the *shell* does). To use `cat` on a file in the current directory whose name *is* `-`, add a path to the filename, such as `./-`.

¹ <sub>The order of the redirections is still important under some circumstances; With `cat <file2 >file1`, for example, `file1` will not be truncated if `file2` is inaccessible (the redirections are parsed from left to right). The relative placement of the word `cat` is however still arbitrary and won't influence this.</sub>

² <sub>See also the question [cat gives different error when opening non-existing file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325706/cat-gives-different-error-when-opening-non-existing-file/).</sub>

---

The fact that the shell sets up the redirections before even executing the command on the command line is why things like these fail and you end up with an empty output file:

```
$ sort file >file
```

Here, the shell will truncate (empty) the file `file` before executing `sort file` and connecting `sort`'s standard output to the file. The `sort` utility will then open `file` and sort its contents (which is nothing). The result (nothing) is passed through the standard output stream to `file`.

The remedy in this particular case (for sorting a file "in-place") is

```
$ sort -o file file
```

or

```
$ sort file >file.sorted && mv file.sorted file
```

or, to ensure that the original file is not deleted (to preserve certain file meta-data),

```
$ cp file file.unsorted && sort file.unsorted >file && rm -f file.unsorted
```

which is more or less what `sort` does when using the `-o` file to specify the output file name.

---

Just to back up the statement that the redirections may precede the actual name of the utility on the command line (my emphasis):

> A "simple command" is a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, **in any sequence**, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator. [[ref: POSIX Shell Command Language 2.9.1 Simple Commands]](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01)

And also about the redirection not being part of the operands of the utility:

> The optional number, redirection operator, and word shall not appear in the arguments provided to the command to be executed (if any). [[ref: POSIX Shell Command Language 2.7 Redirection]](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07)

Comment: Is there some advantage to the form used by the OP? Or is this just someone being fancy?

Comment: Nicely explained.  I wonder if having the shell perform the initial file openings on behalf of the named command has some performance benefits (or detriments) in some situations.  Might it also have implications for access permissions (consider a setuid executable being run by a user logged in with restricted permissions).  Great answer +1.

Comment: @Steve there is no advantage. I've come across one person in this forum who thought that writing `<file1 cat >file2` was more intuitive than `cat <file1 >file2` (or any other permutation).

Comment: @Steve The freedom to move redirections around can be used to make some commands clearer, like a pipeline with input redirection at the beginning `<in foo | bar >out` puts everything in logical order. I'm also fond if `echo >&2 Something bad happened` for error output from shell scripts. But `>out <in cat` is just obfuscation

Comment: @Wossname The most common issue with permissions and redirections is probably conjunction with `sudo`, e.g. `sudo grep something file1 >file2` when in a directory only writable by `root`. The redirection fails even before the `sudo` command is invoked.

Comment: @Wossname Whether the shell or the utility opens a file is less of a performance issue in general. Repeatedly appending to an output file is slow if it requires the shell (or the utility) to re-open the file for each additional bit of data. In those cases it's better to open the file for appending with `>>` once and then iterate over the utility.  This is most often done by placing `>>outfile` after the `done` in the loop, rather than with the invocation of the utility. But, as I said, the difference between letting the utility or the shell open a file is, I assume, minimal.

Comment: @Kusalananda, good points.

Comment: @Wossname BTW, `sudo grep something file1 | sudo tee file2 >/dev/null` will solve the permission issue I mentioned.

Comment: @setht http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/70524

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I've occasionally had cases where I've been running commands like `some -really -long -command -with -lots -of -options -oneOptionIWantToChange > some/annoyingly/long/path 2> some/different/annoyingly/long/path`. Putting the redirections at the beginning would make the option I want to change in a more convenient place. This is obviously quite a rare case though!

Comment: Yup, good answer, and in fact as far as `bash` specifically is concerned, the manual states in Redirection section "redirection operators may precede or appear  anywhere  within  a simple command or may follow a command."

Comment: Something to be aware of: when linking to POSIX with HTML fragments, it's better  to specify the exact edition (like http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition) as fragments have been known to change between editions of a same revision of the spec (a lot of links in answers on this site including of mine are now wrong as the fragments point in the wrong place after the 2016 edition has been released).