# Redirect content under a new line (without further syntax or arguments)

Tags: text-processing, io-redirection, cat, newlines, here-string

I tried these ways to append content to a file:

```
printf "\nsource ~/script.sh" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
echo -e "\nsource ~/script.sh" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
cat >> "/etc/bash.bashrc" <<< "source ~/script.sh"
```

All three ways work. I find the `cat` herestring less comfortable as one needs to read it from the end (after `cat` append this`[end]` to`[start]`).

All way don't automatically break the line and the `\n` syntax for `printf` and `echo` is one I'd personally use as last resort. Moreover, I don't know of any way to add a newline for an herestring, and found no such way in this [documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html).

What I seek is a utility that goes down one line automatically without the need to add any argument or syntax. I tried to read on nix text processing utilities, but found nothing like what I seek. Do you know such a utility?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356118/how-is-this-command-legal-file1-file2-cat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to write the `cat` line "the wrong way", this works just fine (though of course the arrows in the here-string still point in an odd direction):

```
$ cat <<< "some text" >> testfile
$ cat testfile
some text
```

As mentioned in the comments, the here-string adds a newline at the end, while with `printf` and `echo` you used `\n` *in the front* of the string.
`echo` would usually add the tailing newline, just like the here-string, so if you need just that, `echo` should be fine (plus it's a builtin in most shells.)

All your commands work slightly differently with the newlines

```
cat >> file <<< "string"        # newline at end
printf "\nstring" >> file       # newline at beginning
echo -e "\nstring" >> file      # newline at beginning and at the end
```

Frankly, I think it's better to get used to the `\n` notation, but if you don't like it, there's always here-docs (both leading and tailing newlines here):

```
cat >> file <<EOF

some text
EOF
```

Comment: ilkkachu, is there a way to concatenate strings inside `printf` or `echo`, as in: `printf "x" "y" >> ~/file`?

Comment: @user9303970, well, `echo` concatenates the arguments with single spaces. With `printf` you could use something like `printf "%s" this that` to concatenate without a delimiter, or `"%s "` to add a space after each string, but of course printf doesn't add the trailing newline by itself. So I suppose it depends on what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If the file does end in a newline, as all correct POSIX text files must, there is no need to add a newline **before** the text you add to the file.

A way to make sure a file ends in a newline is to execute this:

```
$ sed -i -e '$a\' file
```

That will add a newline **only** if the file is missing the newline.

Then, you can add the text you need with a trailing new line to ensure the text file still ends in a newline:

```
a="source ~/script.sh"
echo  -e "$a" >> file    # with trailing new line
printf "$a\n" >> file    # with trailing new line
 <<< "$a" cat >> file    # with trailing new line
```

Note that the order of the cat command has been changed from the one you posted.

If you need an **additional** leading new line, use:

```
a="source ~/script.sh"
{ echo; echo  -e "$a" ; } >>file
echo -e "\n$a"            >>file
printf '%b' "\n$a\n"      >>file

a=$'\nsource ~/script.sh'
<<<"$a" cat >>file
```

If you want an additional newline with the cat option, use:

```
a=$'\nsource ~/script.sh\n'
<<<"$a" cat >>file
```

that will add **two** trailing new lines, one from the variable `$a` and one (unavoidable) from the `<<<` (here-string).

Answer (score -1):

Just because it is possible, here's a way to make `append` command in python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
with open(sys.argv[2],"a") as f:
     f.write(sys.argv[1] + "\n")
```

And works as so.

```
$ echo "first line" > input.txt
$ ./append  "Hello Unix.se" input.txt
$ cat input.txt 
first line
Hello Unix.se
```

Comment: This, however, appends the newline **after** the text, just as `echo` would. So what's the point?