# Why reverse syntax of output redirection doesn't act as input redirection?

Tags: linux, io-redirection

command 1: `cat file1 > file2` (success)

command 2: `file2 < cat file1` (cat : No such file or directory)

 
I just wanted to know the general syntax of output and input redirections. 
If redirection can happen to file or stream, why command 2 fails?

Comment: command 2 is not valid: file2 is the "executable" and your try to send it cat as input. What do you actual want to do?

Comment: Also basic shell stuff: `>` sends output to a file, `<` uses a file as input.

Comment: @cylgalad Got it now. Please put the second comment as answer.

Comment: @cylagad The command is not invalid (if file2 is a script), but it's not the same as the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirection in

```
cat file1 >file2
```

is an output redirection, while `<` specifies an input redirection.

The line

```
file2 < cat file1
```

is the same as

```
file2 file1 <cat
```

(it does not matter much where the redirection actually occurs as it's handled by the shell in its own parsing step and then removed from the actual command) which means "run `file2` with `file1` as argument, and redirect the standard input from the file `cat`".

The error comes from the shell trying to open `cat` as a file in the current directory. The error occurs before the shell tries to run the command `file2`.

Related: [How is this command legal ? "> file1 < file2 cat"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356118/how-is-this-command-legal-file1-file2-cat)