# Process Substitution in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, process-substitution

Can someone explain to me why I don't see the output of "date" from the below command? For N number for STDIN inputs, it's printing only for last (N-1) commands?

```
[root@RAJ-RHEL6 raj]# cat < <(date) <(hostname) <(uptime) <(cat /etc/resolv.conf)
RAJ-RHEL6.5
 02:22:59 up  2:36,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
nameserver 10.207.26.248
[root@RAJ-RHEL6 raj]#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may only redirect the standard input stream from one place.  You can't expect to be able to redirect it from several files or process substitutions in a single command.

The command

```
cat < <(date) <(hostname) <(uptime) <(cat /etc/resolv.conf)
```

is the same as

```
cat <(hostname) <(uptime) <(cat /etc/resolv.conf) < <(date)
```

i.e., you are giving `cat` three input files, and then you redirect the output of `date` into its standard input.

The `cat` utility will not use its standard input stream if it's given files to work with, but you can get it to do so by using the special `-` filename:

```
cat - <(hostname) <(uptime) <(cat /etc/resolv.conf) < <(date)
```

Note also that the last process substitution is useless and the command is better written written as

```
cat - <(hostname) <(uptime) /etc/resolv.conf < <(date)
```

or, without that redirection of the output of `date`, as

```
cat <(date) <(hostname) <(uptime) /etc/resolv.conf
```

or, with a single command substitution,

```
cat <( date; hostname; uptime; cat /etc/resolv.conf )
```

or, without process substitutions,

```
date; hostname; uptime; cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Related:

- [How is this command legal ? "> file1 < file2 cat"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356118)

Comment: drat !! fastest gun in the web again !! congrat !

Answer (score 2):

as per `man cat`

> Concatenate FILE(s) to standard output.
>
> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

thus if you give FILE, standard input is not read.

this is not a bash feature, it also work (or don't work) with plain files.