# Is there anything special about `< .` and this `echo` behavior?

Tags: bash, shell

I was wondering if there was anything special about `< .` in bash since

`$ mail <destination> < .`

sends an empty email instead of a dot and

`$ echo < .`

doesn't fit anything that I used to know about echo.

After tinkering around, I wonder how can you explain the behavior of `echo` in the following:

`$ echo <` => syntax error

`$ echo < giberish` => error: No such file or directory

`$ echo < . giberish` => `giberish`

`$ echo < .` => blank

`$ echo < "filenameInPWD"` => blank

`$ echo < "randomstring"` => error: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you know what `<` and `.` mean and you're asking about the combination, or is it just the whole lot that you're asking about? Alternatively, what are you expecting the first command to do, and what error were you expecting from the second? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that `mail` as in `$ mail <dest>` is just programmed to put an EOT when it sees a dot alone in a line; it doesn't have anything to do with bash, so I'll remove that from the question.  Regarding `echo` I'll expand a bit on it.

Comment: That's the wrong conclusion. If you want to see what's happening, run each program under `strace` so tht you can see the system calls (although the output is long and you will need patience and persistence to get through it).

Comment: @NickD I'm trying to thing what else it might be before I go through that.  What I see after I type `$ mail root` is satisfyingly clear, even if I admit something intricate might be behind.

Comment: I have tried to explain in my answer.

Comment: Now you have changed your question so that it is mostly about `echo`, rather than about the `< .` redirection. That makes my answer mostly irrelevant (although the answer by @thanasisp is still relevant and answers most of your new question). I wish people did not change questions after answers are submitted except to fix typos.

Comment: I think NickD is right, I suggest to add the initial question also, and include the modification after that, it's not very big totally. So any reader can understand why Nick's answer explains an example with the mail command etc.

Comment: I fixed it as you suggested, take a look

Comment: I see still the initial question is missing, but never mind, you may leave it like this. Please remember in the future, to prepare you question, focus on one problem, take some time to review it and finally post it, so that you need to do only minimum changes and help answers from the beginning to focus into the problem you describe, cheers.

Comment: Tangentially related: [How is this command legal? “> file1 < file2 cat”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356118/how-is-this-command-legal-file1-file2-cat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
strace mail <dest> < .
```

you can see what happened (although you have to look closely). On a Linux system (as a comment notes, other Unix systems may behave differently if a read of a directory succeeds), there are about 200 lines of output, much of it initialization, but there are three very significant lines, in my case lines 153, 165 and 191:

```
...
read(0, 0x556829edb730, 8192)           = -1 EISDIR (Is a directory)
...
write(1, "No message, no subject; hope tha"..., 39No message, no subject; hope that's ok) = 39
...
write(4, "Date: Sat, 10 Oct 2020 23:19:22 "..., 212) = 212
...
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

IOW, it tried to read file descriptor 0 (its standard input) and got an error `EISDIR`: that's because the shell redirected `.` i.e. the current directory as its standard input and `read` is not allowed to read a directory. But the mail program ignored that error, wrote a message on its stdout (file descriptor 1) that there was no message and no subject submitted to it and that it hoped that that was OK, then proceeded to compose a mail message and write it to file descriptor 4, which presumably is plumbed up somehow to send the message (the message consists of 212 characters). Note also that the program exits with 0 status (normal exit).

If you try the same thing with `cat` or `tr` as @thanasisp suggests in his answer, you will see a slightly different result. Those programs still try to read from file descriptor 0 and get the EISDIR error - but they do *NOT* ignore the error; instead, they exit with an error message and non-zero status:

```
$ strace cat < .
...
read(0, 0x7fc27daec000, 131072)         = -1 EISDIR (Is a directory)
write(2, "cat: ", 5cat: )                    = 5
write(2, "-", 1-)                        = 1
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, ": Is a directory", 16: Is a directory)        = 16
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
munmap(0x7fc27daeb000, 139264)          = 0
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

But there is no difference in how `< .` is treated: in both cases, the shell associates a file (the current directory) with file descriptor 0 (the standard input) of the executed program. But the programs choose to respond to the error differently. That's all.

And BTW, the answer by @thanasisp is spot-on and answers most of your questions (even if it elides a bit the subtle difference between the `mail` command and e.g. `tr` or `cat`, which is what I concentrate on in this answer).

Comment: Honestly the most useful thing I've learned from this is `strace` and your usage demo to disambiguate the fact that the dot is the current working directory in this case (until your demo to me the dot could have been something else, like "source" as in https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html).  I mean, I know that the dot in bash is usually the current working directory, that's one of the first things you learn.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful.

Comment: ... but I still think that the other answer is the correct answer to your (new) question.

Comment: @NickD Notice that on some Unix systems (FreeBSD, Solaris) reading a directory as an ordinary file may succeed -- and `mail dest <.` will get the filenames interspersed with binary junk, and may even send something ;-)

Comment: Thanks: added a note to that effect. Note that on Linux, `mail` does send something (an empty message), even though the `read()` returns an error.

Answer (score 2):

The dot stands for the current directory, you can see that in typical usual commands like `find .`, `cp path/filename .` etc, it means "here". Also dot is the synonym of the `source` command, you can see that by typing `man .`.

In your case, dot is being used as the current directory, because this syntax:

```bsh
command < path/to/something
```

is a redirection into the standard input of the command as you can see in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html), while this syntax:

```
command < path/to/something argument
```

is the same as above, with additionally one argument, the same like this:

```
command argument < path/to/something
```

---

So in your case, `echo` does not complain because it does not read its standard input at all, reads only the following string and prints it.

You can see that better with other commands, for example `tr` that reads only its standard input:

```bsh
tr < . 'a' 'b' # or tr 'a' 'b' < .
tr: read error: Is a directory
tr < file 'a' 'b' # works.
```

Comment: can you please take a look at the edited question?

Comment: I have seen that you modified the question, I think you can still find an answer for your main point above. Also follow the link to the bash manual: in the right side of this redirection a filename is expected, so the *content* of the file is being redirected.

Comment: To the OP: the important point to your (new) question is that "...`echo`...does not read its standard input at all" to quote from the answer. It only cares about the command line arguments and those can come before or after the (irrelevant in this case) input redirection.