# while loop compare timestamp

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to generate a series of timestamp and compare with the max limit. I wanted to use the while loop to check this.

Here is my code.

```
start_ts='2021-08-07 15:00:00'
end_ts='2021-08-10 05:00:00'

while [ "$start_ts" > "$end_ts" ]
do 
  echo $start_ts
    start_ts=$(date -ud "$start_ts +0 + 30 minutes" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
done
```

But this loop is going and going, not stopping at `$end_ts` value.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When used with `[ ... ]`, the unquoted `>` is a redirection operator.  This means that you now probably have a file named `2021-08-10 05:00:00` in your current directory, created by redirecting the output of the `[` command to file.

The command

```bsh
[ "$start_ts" > "$end_ts" ]
```

may also be written

```bsh
[ "$start_ts" ] >"$end_ts"
```

(see e.g. [How is this command legal? "> file1 < file2 cat"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356118/how-is-this-command-legal-file1-file2-cat)). This is a test for whether the string `"$start_ts"` is non-empty, and the output of that test (which is nothing because `[` does not output anything) is redirected to the file `$end_ts`.

When used with `[[ ... ]]`, the `>` is [a string comparison operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) that tests whether two strings are sorted in a particular way.  This is likely what you want to use, but to get the logic right you'd use  `<`, or swap the arguments around `>`, or use `until` instead of `while`.

---

Another approach would be to skip the string comparisons completely and instead use integer comparisons of Unix timestamps:

```bsh
start_ts=$( date -d '2021-08-07 15:00:00' +%s )
end_ts=$( date -d '2021-08-10 05:00:00' +%s )

while [ "$start_ts" -lt "$end_ts" ]; do 
    printf '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T\n' "$start_ts"
    start_ts=$(( start_ts + 1800 ))
done
```

Since there is no call to GNU `date` inside the loop, this runs many times faster than the original code (about 50 times faster on my system).

Comment: Or they could use `[ "$start_ts" '>' "$end_ts" ]`. `>` is not a standard `[` operator, but many implementations support it as an extension, including (but not limited to) the `[` builtin of those shells that support the `[[...]]` ksh-style construct. POSIXly, you can use `expr` instead of `[`/`test`.

Comment: Why not use `-gt` instead? That works with single brackets.

Comment: @user000001 They are comparing strings. `-gt` requires two integers. But yes, if they formatted their timestamps as Unix timestamps with `%s`, it would be appropriate to use `-gt` or `-lt`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Right, that's a good point, thanks.

Comment: @user000001 Thanks for the input! See updated answer.