# What does this command do? Redirection at start and end of command

Tags: bash, io-redirection, macos

I have the following command:

```bsh
2>&1 compiler \
    --flag1 \
    --flag2 \
    --option X=10 \
    build \
    2>&1 | tee -a output.log
```

I'm not entirely sure what is the behavior, is it redundant and not needed?

I've used the redirection at the start to print to stderr

```bsh
>&2 echo "Diagnostic Title"
```

I'm going over but struggling a bit and see no mention of start vs end of command spec:

- https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The second `2>&1` seems redundant. Related: [How is this command legal? "> file1 < file2 cat"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356118)

Answer (score 4):

Some things to keep in mind:

- redirections can appear anywhere in the command
- redirections are processed left-to-right (but only after the pipeline is set up)

Given these 2 points, we can see the first one redirects stderr to whatever stdout is currently pointing to. (Here, the pipeline.) Then the second one does exactly the same thing. Since stdout *has not changed in between*, the 2nd redirection is indeed redundant.

Also, this one is very important and is a fairly common source of questions here:

- redirections are processed *before* the command is actually invoked:

  ```bsh
  sed 'some sed program' myfile > myfile
  ```

  truncates myfile *first* and then launches sed, which has a zero-length input file to process.

The [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356120/4667) to the related question that @Kusalananda points to goes into greater depth.